# Not able to get the 'Open' state of Dropdown

Tags: bootstrap-4

In my Bootstrap@4.1.3 - I am trying to show a dropdown with open state by adding "show" class added. but not works. any one help me?

here is my html:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="btn-group show" >
            <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle">Manage Recipe <span class="caret"></span></button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Shopping List</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Edit Recipe</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Delete Recipe</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/emyot8fv/)

Comment: bro for working dropdown you need bootstrapjs and specially popper.js

Comment: I just wanted to show the drop-down contents without using js

Comment: without js is not possible, so behalf of using dropdown you can easily use <select> operator

Answer (score 0):

try to use all links then it will works...

also you missed `data-toggle="dropdown"` in this button

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
      About Us
    </button>
```

```html
<html>
<head> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">                                         
  <div class="dropdown show">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
      About Us
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
     <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Our Story</a>
     <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Our Team</a>
     <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Contact Us</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I updated your fiddle [check here](http://jsfiddle.net/emyot8fv/2/)